# Invalid Syntax - Logic Error

Tags: python

Can someone check over this bit of code? I'm getting an invalid syntax without an explanation. It needs to know when an input between 8-40 to go through the overtime_hours = 0, and when the input is 41-86 it needs to go through the overtime_hours = original_hours - 40.

```
while original_hours < 8 or original_hours > 40:
    overtime_hours = 0
elif original_hours > 41 or original_hours < 86:
    overtime_hours = original_hours - 40
```

This is for a homework assignment, and is a part of a much larger payroll program.

Comment: Syntax errors are not logic errors -- a logic error is an error in which the syntax is well-formed, but the control flow or otherwise runtime effects are not what is intended.

Comment: don't mix while with elif,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `elif`, you must have an `if` first. Also, your conditions seems bad, you could try this:

```
if 8 <= original_hours <= 40:
    overtime_hours = 0
elif 41 <= original_hours <= 86:
    overtime_hours = original_hours - 40
```

Or this:

```
if original_hours in range(8, 41):
    overtime_hours = 0
elif original_hours in range(41, 87):
    overtime_hours = original_hours - 40
```

**Note** that `range(a, b)` includes `a` but doesn't include `b`. That's why you should use `range(8, 40+1)`

Comment: Chaining comparisons can make it even more clear: `8 <= original_hours <= 40` and doesn't create a throwaway list.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor I always forget that feature. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if 8 < original_hours < 86:
    worked_hours = min(original_hours,40)
    overtime_hours = max(0, original_hours-40)
# define your special cases for hours <= 8 or hours >= 86
```

In general you don't ever want to change your `original_hours` in a payroll program, for the same reason you wouldn't want your employer being able to change your clock-in/clock-out times without your say-so. I made a copy of that which makes out at 40 hours and set that to `worked_hours`. `overtime_hours`, then, is zero if `original_hours <= 40`, by virtue of the fact that `max(n,m)` gives you the biggest of `n,m`. If `original_hours - 40` is negative, it would return zero. Otherwise, it will give you how many hours OVER FORTY the employee worked. *Capisce?*

As Christian explained in another answer, the reason you're getting a syntax error is that in order to use `elif`, you have to have an `if` first! The syntax for `if/elif/else` blocks is:

```
if condition:
    do_stuff
elif other_condition:
    do_other_stuff
elif ...
    do_...
else:
    default_case
```

`while`, on the other hand, may be a good way to see how many work weeks were filled (maybe your employee earns 8 hours paid time off per week worked, and you're somehow against floor division)

```
PTO = 0
while hours_worked > 40:
    PTO += 8
    hours_worked -= 40
```